# Laravel: Can't change db connection from local to remote

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Well, this is killing me.

I tried everything possible to change the connection inside a Laravel project but nothing works and keeps tied to a local database connection that I have. 
These are the two databases that my project has:

[image]

I worked most of the time with the local one, but I need to run some commands on the production one (I can connect easily with MySQL Workbench since my IP is on the whitelist), so I need to change it. My "**.env**" and my "**database.php**" config are pointing to the ip of the production database, I have run all the commands for clearing the cache `php artisan config:clear`->`php artisan cache:clear`-> `php artisan config:cache`, and after that I see also my **bootstrap/cache/config.php** with the proper data.

I know that is reading my .env file because if I change `APP_ENV=production` to `APP_ENV=testdummychange` and running `php artisan env` is retrieving the change as expected.

**Tinker**

By using Tinker to check the connection I see:

[image]

And I'm invoking a Model from Tinker that exists both in production and local, but in local has some dummy test and ALWAYS retrieves the value from the local one:

[image]

And, despite the warnings you can see the same result instantly, I mean, I know that nothing is cached:

[image]

Is good to mention that I'm using XAMPP to run the MySQL Service on port 3306, and despite the lack of common sense I'm starting to think that this client is storing some credentials or something, because there is not any other place where I can place the DB credentials on a Laravel project.

Is there any other possible place that is storing my db credentials on a Laravel/PHP project? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Did you try querying another model to check what data is retrieved?

Comment: I just did it, as expected, the result is still comming from the local DB. I tried with an element that exists in PROD and doesn't in LOCAL, the result was "null"

Comment: What is the result for running `php artisan tinker` with: `env('DB_HOST')`?

Comment: uhm, is "null" which is weird, because my .env file has DB_HOST=35.246.XXX.XXX, do you have a clue?

Comment: What is the output for: `config('database.connections.' . config('database.default'))['host']` ?

Comment: The production IP: 35.246.XXX.XXX . At the beginning of my database.php I have 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql') which has the correct configuration as well

Comment: What happens if you run: `DB::select('SELECT * FROM precalcs WHERE id=75408')->all();`

Comment: With "->all() is giving an error. Without the "->all()" is retriving the same element element shown in the picture with '"entity_type": "TestForStackOverflow", I mean, the same element existing in LOCAL, not the PROD one.

Comment: what is the output for: `DB::select('select host from information_schema.processlist WHERE ID=connection_id()')`?

Comment: [
     {#3891
       +"host": "",
     },
   ]
The output is the following. Sorry the delay Marteen, thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe interesting? [How to Run Laravel Using Multiple Database Connections](https://medium.com/teknomuslim/how-to-run-laravel-using-multiple-database-connections-d7e8dcb7ed2a)

Comment: What is the output for: `DB::select('select USER()')`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all thanks for @MaartenDevand and @Ryan Vincent who tried to help me.

For those who could be facing a problem like this, I found out that the `DB_SOCKET` configured on my `.env` file which configures the "unix socket" wasn't working remotely and that was causing my connection string to be overriden.

Simply removing the `DB_SOCKET` key, everything is working again.